# WAMP not starting on boot, even though I put a shortcut to wampmanager.exe in Startup Folder

Tags: windows-10, boot

I'm trying to get WAMP to start on boot.

I made a shortcut to wampmanager.exe, and put it in `C:\Users\[MyUserName]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

But it doesn't do it.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know WAMP runs as a service.  If it has been installed then it is probably, already registered.

1. Login as Adminstrator
2. Click Start
3. Run `services.msc`
4. Look for services starting with `wamp`
5. Right click and go to Properties
6. Set `Start type` to **Automatic**
7. Reboot

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: My wamp services are grayed out, I can't change their properties  ¿Any suggestion? 